# Simple python transposed (to 0?)

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

Im currently analyzing coded scripts for my professor. What I can't get in my head is this one line of code:

When df is transposed df.t, next line states T0 = df.t[0]

Why can't I get my head around this df.t[0]. What does it really mean?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Next line of code, if you need it in context, is df.t-T0, which I read as getting sequence of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a dataframe which is indexed by integers starting with 0, and then transpose it and call it `df.t`, then `df.t[0]` will give you the column which is named `0`, which used to be the zeroth row in the dataframe.

Comment: Peter! I get it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Cool :) If that was helpful you can explicitly **accept the answer** with the check-mark... ;) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done deal. Thank you again!